# Solve $x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(x^2+y^2)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation - $$x\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(x^2+y^2).$$

It most probably involves a change of variables so that it becomes variable separable.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

If, as suggested by Amzoti, you start with $y=v x$, $y'=v+x v'$, after simplification the equation becomes $$\frac{dv}{dx}=v^2+1$$ which is separable.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y(x) = x \, u(x)$ to obtain $y' = x u' + u$ and the differential equation becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx} = u^{2} + 1.
\end{align}
Now make the substitution 
\begin{align}
u(x) = - \frac{w'(x)}{w(x)}
\end{align}
to obtain the differential equation $w'' + w = 0$ which has the solution $w(x) = A \cos(x) + B \sin(x)$. Working backwards the solution to the equation in question is then
\begin{align}
y(x) = x \left( \frac{ A \sin(x) - B \cos(x)}{A \cos(x) + B \sin(x) } \right). 
\end{align}

Comment: Don't you think that $\frac{dx}{du} =\frac{1}{1+u^{2}}$ is easier ?